# move to other tab

Tags: android

I have an application with 3 tab (tab1, tab2, tab3) How can I move to the tab2 if a press a bottom in tab1.
I have this....

```
    Resources res= getResources();
        TabHost tabHost= getTabHost();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;
        Intent intent;

        // initialize a TabSpect for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        intent= new Intent().setClass(this, StockMarket.class);
        spec= tabHost.newTabSpec("1").setIndicator("Stock Market", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.grafica))
        .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent= new Intent().setClass(this, Info.class);
        spec= tabHost.newTabSpec("2").setIndicator("Data", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.puzzle)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent= new Intent().setClass(this, Profile.class);
        spec= tabHost.newTabSpec("3").setIndicator("Profile", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.toolbox)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent= new Intent().setClass(this, Graphic.class);
        spec= tabHost.newTabSpec("Graphic").setIndicator("Graphic", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.chart)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This might help you -

```
getTabHost().setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

    int i = getTabHost().getCurrentTab();
    Log.i("TAB NUMBER", + i);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, It was worked for me.
set a method to my main class, which extends TabActivity let's call it "MainActivity"

```
 public TabHost getMyTabHost() { 
 return tabHost; 
 }
```

Then add my tab activity class;

```
MainActivity ta = (MainActivity) this.getParent();
TabHost t = ta.getMyTabHost();
t.setCurrentTab(0);
```

you can set tabs with int in setCurrentTab(0).